# How to prove this Bessel equality?

Tags: bessel-functions

I've got a problem with proving this Bessel's equality:
$$x^2 = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n)^2 J_{2n}(x)$$

The Bessel generating function is $\exp(\frac{x}{2}(t-t^{-1})) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{n}(x)t^n$.

I think the solution should is replace $t$ with some other forms and proving the equality by comparing the coefficient,  but I can't find a way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):
$$
e^{ix\cos t}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)e^{int}
$$
Differentiate both sides twice with reapect to $t$:
$$
-(x^2\sin^2t+ix\cos t)e^{ix\cos t}=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n^2 J_n(x)e^{int}
$$
taking $t=\dfrac\pi 2$ and combine $n$ with $-n$ terms and using $J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^nJ_n(x)$ we get:
$$
x^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 J_n(x)[e^{in\pi/2}+(-1)^ne^{-in\pi/2}]
$$
The expression in the square bracket vanishes for odd $n$ and is $2$ otherwise, so we get:
$$
x^2=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n)^2 J_{2n}(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer!

Comment: You may say that the first equality comes from the one mentioned by the OP by replacing $t$ with $e^{it}$.

Comment: Sure - nice comment @Gary